# Paginate doesn't word in grails

Tags: java, grails, pagination

I have problem with paginate, I use grails 2.4.4

This my index.gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <g:paginate controller="user" action="index" total="${userTotal}"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
class UserController {
    def index() {
        List<User> users = User.findAll()
    
        render(view: "index", model: [users: users, userTotal: 4])
    }
}
```

In the console I don't have any error and in my page I see nothing.
Array users isn't empty, I checked.

Comment: Paginate just shows pagination controls.  Since you have 4 users (and default page size is 10 I think?) that would show nothing.  You'll still need to list the users in a table or whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my solution:

gsp:

```
 <div class="content scaffold-list">
        <g:form controller="user" action="index">
            <label>Input user's name:</label>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <g:textField name="userName"/>
    
                <g:submitButton name="search"/>
            </div>
    
    
            <g:each var="user" in="${users}">
                <p>User with name: ${user.name}</p>
            </g:each>
        </g:form>
    
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate controller="user" action="index"
                        max="5" total="${userCount}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
def index(String userName) {
    initUsersAndPokemons()

    PagedResultList users = fourthService.findUsersByName(
            userName,
            params.int('max', 5),
            params.int('offset', 0))

    [users: users, userCount: users.getTotalCount()]
}
```

service:

```
PagedResultList findUsersByName(String userName, int max, int offset) {
    BuildableCriteria bc = User.createCriteria()
    bc.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
            like('name',userName)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render(view: "index", model: [users: users, userTotal: 4])
```

You have hardcoded `userTotal` to be 4.  The `paginate` tag defaults to 10 items per page, so pagination is not required.

If you are concerned about pagination then `User.findAll()` is probably a bad idea because it will return all of the data.

Default scaffolding will do something like this which is a better idea...

Controller action:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond userService.list(params), model:[userCount: userService.count()]
}
```

GORM Data Service:

```
import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(User)
interface UserService {

    User get(Serializable id)

    List<User> list(Map args)

    Long count()

    void delete(Serializable id)

    User save(User user)

}
```

The relevant GSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#list-user" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="list-user" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <f:table collection="${userList}" />

            <div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${userCount ?: 0}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you *really* don't want to use a service (highly recommended that you do) then you could change the controller to do something like this...

```
params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
respond User.list(params), model:[userCount: User.count()]
```

Comment: In the example given by OP, there's nothing actually rendering the list.  I think this is probably the underlying problem.  That said, scaffolding would certainly address the issue.

Comment: @Daniel Agreed.  The GSP shown above would render the list, and the controller code should allow the `<g:paginate ...` tag to work.

Comment: In particular, `<f:table collection="${userList}" />` should render a table showing all of the entities in `userList`.

Comment: Thanks for ansfer my key error was that I used: model: [users: users, instead: User.list(params)